# Make garbage collector happier in Browser

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, garbage-collection, webrtc

We have following code.

```
            recorderProcess : function (e) {
                    var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
                    var samples = this.resampler.resampler(left);
                    var leftSix = convertFloat32ToInt16(samples);
                    var send = G711.encode(leftSix, {
                        alaw: this.encMode == "alaw" ? true : false
                    });  
                    vApp.wb.utility.audioSend(send);
                }
```

https://github.com/vidyamantra/virtualclass/blob/86a474e2c8e3eb3877fc12d947890984cbc7fb5c/src/media.js#L329

We are capturing audio (Raw PCM) from browser, encoding to to G711 and sending it over websocket.
Problem with this code is that it is making browser Garbage Collector (GC) aggressive.

How can we make GC happier so that it has to do less work?

We tried making variables global but that is not helping us.

**UPDATE 1**

Ading Live code and Chrome Timeline Memory View.

http://jsfiddle.net/s05q4o3p/

[image: Chrome showing GC in action]

Comment: What is the GC like when it is "aggressive"? What is the problem?

Comment: GC is collecting about 2-8MB of data in every few hundred MS. Sometimes it leads to crash in Chrome.

Comment: I don't see why that is a problem. You are dealing with large amounts of data much or all of which becomes unnecessary immediately after capture so GC is right freeing that data. I'm not sure it's the GC that leads to instability of the browser, it's rather the amount of data. Anyway, if GC didn't clean the data, that would lead to even more server problems eating up memory.

Comment: Any way to reuse or pool variables so that it reuses allocated memory - http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/ ? We got following answer from Google Chrome's bug post "This is effectively an out-of-memory crash. You could try to reduce the page's memory usage, but that may be difficult given the nature of the content. It is probably generating a lot of garbage that may not be recycled quickly enough."